# Get citations as superscript instead of squared brackets using natbib

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, citing, natbib, overleaf

I am using natbib for referencing for a nature journal and using naturemag as bibliography style. I am facing 2 issues with my code:

1- The references appear as [1] square brackets rather than superscripts, though I am defining the option 'super' in the package options.

2- In the author name of my references, '*et al*' appears in italics, and the Nature journal requirement is that it should be in non-italic 'et al'.

Please find the code below:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{square,comma,numbers,sort&compress,super}{natbib}
\documentclass[aps,prl,twocolumn,a4paper,superscriptaddress]{revtex4}

\usepackage[paperwidth=215mm,paperheight=300mm,centering,hmargin=1.6cm,vmargin=2cm]{geometry}
% \usepackage{multibbl}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}

%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{latexsym,stmaryrd}
% \usepackage[square,numbers,super]{natbib}
% \usepackage[sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{siunitx} % SI units
\usepackage{physics} %physics like absolute value, divergence, etc.
\usepackage{chemformula} %correct chemical notation
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{gensymb}

\setcounter{topnumber}{2}
\setcounter{bottomnumber}{2}
\setcounter{totalnumber}{5}
\renewcommand{\topfraction}{0.95}
\renewcommand{\bottomfraction}{0.95}
\renewcommand{\textfraction}{0.05}
\renewcommand{\floatpagefraction}{0.95}


\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\bfseries}{}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{2.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{0.2ex plus .2ex}
\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]{\bfseries}{}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{2.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{0.2ex plus .2ex}

\renewcommand{\figurename}{\textbf{Fig.}}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\fnum@figure}{{\normalfont\bfseries \figurename~\thefigure}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\bibliographystyle{naturemag}
\bibliography{ref}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding. I removed 'number' from options and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

- On your first question: I suggest you get rid of the lines

  ```
   \PassOptionsToPackage{square,comma,numbers,sort&compress,super}{natbib}
  ```

  and

  ```
   % \usepackage[square,numbers,super]{natbib}
   % \usepackage[sort&compress]{natbib}
  ```

  and replace them with the single instruction

  ```
  \setcitestyle{super,comma,sort&compress}
  ```

  This works because the `revtex` document class loads the `natbib` package automatically.
- On your second question: I would like to suggest you proceed as follows

  - Find the file `naturemag.bst` in your TeX distribution, make a copy of this file, and name the copy, say, `naturemag-etalnoitalics.bst`. (You're free to come up with a shorter name...)
  - Open `naturemag-etalnoitalics.bst` in a text editor. The program you use to edit your tex files will do fine.
  - Find the three instances of `bbl.etal` (other than the very first instance). The first instance should say `" " * bbl.etal * emphasize *`; change it to `" " * bbl.etal *`. The second and third instances should have the word `emphasize` on the following line. Delete (or comment out) the two lines that say `emphasize`.
  - Save the file `naturemag-etalnoitalics.bst` in the directory that contains your main tex file.
  - In your main tex file, change `\bibliographystyle{naturemag}` to `\bibliographystyle{naturemag-etalnoitalics.bst}`. The run a full recompile-cycle: LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response.
On the first question: This works for the citations appearing as superscripts, but in the bibliography section, the references still appear with square brackets, though they should appear without square brackets.

On the second question: I am using Overleaf. Is it possible to access naturemag.bst file using overleaf? If yes, kindly let me know how I can access it. 

looking forward to hearing from you.

Comment: @AliBabar - Sorry, I don't use Overleaf. But I understand that Overleaf has an online help desk that's staffed by excellent folks. Please go ask your overleaf-specific questions there. I'm pretty sure the answer to your question, "Is it possible to access naturemag.bst file using overleaf", is "yes". However, since I don't use overleaf myself, I'm in no position to make strong assurances.

Comment: @AliBabar - I assume you're using the `revtex4` document class for a reason, e.g., a journal's editorial desk has instructed you to use that class. As such, I would *not* mess with the formatting and design decisions embedded by the `revtex4` class. Editorial offices are notoriously short-fused and don't appreciate users messing with layout decisions. Hence, do learn to live with the square brackets. Really, how bad can it be to have to look at square brackets?  If you really, really can't stand the square brackets, do figure out which other document classes you may be permitted to employ.

Comment: HI, thanks for the suggestion and your response. Btw I figured out the way to remove square brackets in the bibliography section by using the following command: \renewcommand\bibnumfmt[1]{#1.}

I will write to overleaf helpdesk to resolve the 'et al' issue.

Comment: @AliBabar - Happy to hear that you've managed to answer one of your question on your own.

Comment: I have also resolved the 'et al' issue with your method by manually uploading the naturemag.bst file in my project on Overleaf and then following your instructions. Thanks alot, I was stuck with this issue for sometime now but your response was very clear.